# multiple condition in fancy indexing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am new to python and am trying to some simple classification on raster image.
Basically, I am reading a TIF image as a 2D array and do some calculating and manipulation on it. For classification part, I am trying to create 3 empty arrays for land, water, and clouds. These classes will be assigned a value of 1 under multiple conditions, and eventually assigning these classes as landclass=1, waterclass=2, cloudclass=3 respectively.

apparently I can assign all values in an array to 1 under one condition
like this:

```
     crop = gdal.Open(crop,GA_ReadOnly)
     crop = crop.ReadAsArray()
     rows,cols = crop.shape
     mode = int(stats.mode(crop, axis=None)[0])
     water = np.empty(shape(row,cols),dtype=float32)
     land = water
     clouds = water
```

than I have something like this (output):

```
     >>> land
     array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           ..., 
           [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
     >>> land[water==0]=1
     >>> land
     array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
            [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
            [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
            ..., 
            [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
            [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
            [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
     >>> land[crop>mode]=1
     >>> land
     array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
            [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
            [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
            ..., 
            [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
            [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
            [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
```

But how can I have the values in "land" equal to 1 under a couple of conditions without altering the shape of the array?
I tried to do this

```
land[water==0,crop>mode]=1
```

and I got ValueError. And I tried this

```
land[water==0 and crop>mode]=1
```

and python asks me to use a.all() or a.all()....

For only one condition, the result is exactly what I want, and I have to do it in order to get the result. eg (this is what I have in my actual code):

```
water[band6 < b6_threshold]=1
water[band7 < b7_threshold_1]=1
water[band6 > b6_threshold]=1
water[band7 < b7_threshold_2]=1

land[band6 > b6_threshold]=1
land[band7 > b7_threshold_2]=1
land[clouds == 1]=1
land[water == 1]=1
land[b1b4 < 0.5]=1
land[band3 < 0.1)]=1    

clouds[land == 0]=1
clouds[water == 0]=1
clouds[band6 < (b6_mode-4)]=1
```

I found this is a bit confusing and I would like to combine all conditions within one statement... Any suggestion on that?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can multiply the boolean arrays for something like "and":

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> a[(a > 1) * (a < 3)] = 99
>>> a
array([ 1, 99,  3,  4])
```

And you can add them for something like "or":

```
>>> a[(a > 1) + (a < 3)] = 123
>>> a
array([123, 123, 123, 123])
```

Alternatively, if you prefer to think of boolean logic rather than True and False being 0 and 1, you can also use the operators `&` and `|` to the same effect.

Comment: Try like this:  `land[(water==0) & (crop > mode)] = 1`

Comment: ohh seems like it works! one more questiion,can I have multiple conditions using that expression? thank you